# Is boost::asio::strand broken on Ubuntu 11.04 (boost_all_dev 1.42)

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, boost, g++, boost-asio

I have a program which uses an io_service and several threads.

It instantiates some number of socket objects. These objects each have a strand for synchronization. All calls to async_read(), async_write(), and similar functions go through strand_.wrap(boost::bind(...)). Each object also has an int interlock_ variable that is initialized to 0.

Inside one of these functions (the on-data-receive callback), I do the following:

```
Class::startRead(...)
{
...
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(ptr, 16384), boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
        strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&EagerConnection::on_read, this, placeholders::error, placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
}

Class::on_read(...)
{
...
    startRead();
    assert(0 == __sync_fetch_and_add(&interlock_, 1));
    onData_();
    assert(1 == __sync_fetch_and_add(&interlock_, -1));
}
```

Because everything is synchronized through the strand, that first assert should never fire. However, it does fire! When I check the value in GDB, the end value of interlock_ is 2, which means that two separate calls to on_read() are active at the same time.

Does this mean that boost::asio::strand is broken? (I've already checked that I don't have any re-entrancy within the completion function -- the onData_ signal handler does not re-call on_data()).

Can the "early" startRead somehow cause an immediate re-entry? (Both the semantics of async_x and strand seem to indicate it can't)

If you really, really want to see the full context of the class, it's available as a gist: https://gist.github.com/979212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spotted a few minor(?) issues:

- Minor: The initialization order of `interlock_` and `strand_` is switched. Fix it by declaring `interlock_` `_after_` the strand_ member;
- The `readIn` function returns no value (uninitialized data). You probably intend to return `n`?

---

Good news:

- Running with valgrind turned up clear.
- Running with helgrind turned up clear (but: I'm not using threads in my minimal example, I guess; Don't know about `boost::asio` and `boost::signals` internals).

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to reproduce things, but my installation fails to raise the asserts when doing this.

I tacked on the following fragment at the end of the gist:

```
int split(std::string const &src, char ch, std::string &oLeft, std::string &oRight)
{
    std::size_t pos = src.find(ch);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
    {
        oLeft = src;
        oRight.clear();
        return 1;
    } else
    {
        oLeft = src.substr(0, pos);
        oRight = src.substr(pos+1);
        return 2;
    }
}

namespace {

    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    EagerConnection c(svc);

    void onconnect()
    {
        std::cout << "ONCONNECT" << std::endl;
        const char data[] = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"; 
        c.writeOut(data, sizeof(data));
    }

    void ondata()
    {
        std::cout << "ONDATA" << std::endl;
        std::ostringstream oss;
        char buf[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = c.readIn(buf, 1024)))
            oss.write(buf, read);
        std::cout << "response: " << oss.str() << std::endl;
    }

    void ondisconnect()
    {
        std::cout << "ON__DIS__CONNECT" << std::endl;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc>1 && argv[1])
    {
        c.onConnect_.connect(&onconnect);
        c.onData_.connect(&ondata);
        c.onDisconnect_.connect(&ondisconnect);


        c.open(argv[1]);
        svc.run();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm really trying to do the SimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork. My connect/reconnect is working nicely (including the increasing backoff time).

I compile this with

```
strand: strand.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Werror -o $@ $^ -g -O0 -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_signals -lpthread
```

And invoke it with

```
./strand 127.0.0.1:6767
```

I have a responding script sitting there doing (basically)

```
netcat -l -p 6767 -e rev
```

One other thing to note: the write buffer never seems to actually be sent/flushed *until* I interrupt the `strand` tester (client side). This happens regardless how large I make `data`... This is probably due to a step I'm missing?

**Edit**:

Tested identical on

- ubuntu meerkat, gcc 4.4.5, boost 1.42.0
- debian sid, gcc 4.5.2-8, boost 1.46.1

Comment: Thanks for the attempt! It may be that the installation I'm using (10.04 LTS) has some bug that's fixed in later versions. Note that I'm pretty much stuck to that version, though.